# ADFS 2016, MVC and WEB.API Tokens and Claims

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, adfs

I'm currently developing an .Net MVC application with a Web.API backend both of which use ADFS 2016 for authentication. The Web.API itself is working as expected however I am having some issues with the ADFS configuration for the MVC application itself.

Based on this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/enabling-oauth-confidential-clients-with-ad-fs-2016 I can configure a new Server Application in ADFS and use those details in my MVC app to authenticate users via ADFS and subsequently request an authorization code for the Web.API back-end on behalf of the current user. However the problem is that I cannot customise the claims that are issued to the MVC application in the id_token with properties from Active Directory and from my current research don't think this is actually possible?

Alternatively, based on this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/customize-id-token-ad-fs-2016 if I configure a Native Application and Website in ADFS and use those details in my MVC app I can customise the claims that are issued in the id_token to my hearts content but I don't know how to request an access token for the back-end Web.API.

Sorry if the background has gone on for a while but is it possible with the latter scenario for me to request an access token for the back-end API? If so how?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yeah - had the same problem which I didn't resolve. The web API in the second reference is actually a "web app" so I was thinking of adding another web API as the real API?

Comment: Yeah, my current plan is to configure a server application and two web api's, I'll then use the server application and one of the web api's for the MVC app and the other web api for the API.

BTW, your blog has been really helpful whilst I've been getting this setup. Thanks :)

Comment: Okay, so I've tried this and run in to another issue! In ADFS I've configured a Server Application and two Web APIs, one of which is used to secure the actual API and the other is used to manage the custom claims for the server application. The problem with this approach is that I call `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync` to get the claims for the ServerApplication but when I then call `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync` to get the access code for the API I get the error `MSIS9612: The authorization code received in 'code' parameter is invalid` Any ideas?

Comment: I think you can only use a code once. So you need to get a new code and then a new token.

Comment: I'm probably missing something and it's probably very straight forwards but how do I get a new code?

Comment: Hey Padwah, do you have any updates or have you figured out alternative solutions?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I've temporarily shelved the project and moved on to other things. Will update in future if I make any progress!